# How to run a github actions job on workflow failure?

Tags: github, github-actions

I want to run a notification job that lets me know that my workflow failed, is there a way to do that without having to `needs` every job and checking the status of each one?

This is how I would have to do it now but it gets cumbersome if I have a ton of jobs:

```
jobs:
  first-job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    steps:
      - exit 0


  second-job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    steps:
      - exit 1

  notify-job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    needs: [first-job, second-job]
    if: ${{ always() && (needs.first-job.result == 'failure' || needs.second-job.result == 'failure') }}
    steps:
      - ./notify.sh
```

I want to simply check if the workflow failed in any capacity at the end, i.e. if any job failed, is that possible?

I see this documentation to check if the triggering workflow failed (https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#running-a-workflow-based-on-the-conclusion-of-another-workflow).

Is there a way to run a `finally` or `ensure` status check at the end of the **current** workflow?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found this less verbose syntax:

```
if: ${{ always() && contains(needs.*.result, 'failure') }}
```

Meaning, if any of the jobs listed in `needs` return "failure" then run this job...

Source: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#contains

Answer (score 2):

Github partner [brightran](https://github.community/u/brightran) stated in [this post](https://github.community/t/how-get-the-status-of-previous-jobs/17555):

> By default, once a step in a running job fails, all the subsequent
> steps in this job will be skipped and this job will be marked as
> failed. If you want the subsequent steps still execute, you can add
> the if conditional (if: always()) in each subsequent step.
>
> Add 2 extra steps at the end of the job1 and job2, and set the 2 steps
> always execute (if: always()). The first one is used to create a text
> file and write the job status into it, and the second one is used to
> upload this text file as an artifact. In job3, you also need to add
> the steps to download the artifacts and read the statuses of jo1 and
> jo2.

Using this workflow as demo:

```yaml
jobs:
  JOB_01:
    name: Job 01
    . . .
    steps:
      - name: Some steps of job 01
      . . .
      - name: Create file status_job01.txt and write the job status into it
        if: always()
        run: |
          echo ${{ job.status }} > status_job01.txt

      - name: Upload file status_job01.txt as an artifact
        if: always()
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v1
        with:
          name: pass_status_job01
          path: status_job01.txt

  JOB_02:
    name: Job 02
    . . .
    steps:
      - name: Some steps of job 02
      . . .
      - name: Create file status_job02.txt and write the job status into it
        if: always()
        run: |
          echo ${{ job.status }} > status_job02.txt

      - name: Upload file status_job02.txt as an artifact
        if: always()
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v1
        with:
          name: pass_status_job02
          path: status_job02.txt

  JOB_03:
    needs: [JOB_01, JOB_02]
    if: always()
    name: Job 03
    . . .
    steps:
      - name: Download artifact pass_status_job01
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v1
        with:
          name: pass_status_job01

      - name: Download artifact pass_status_job02
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v1
        with:
          name: pass_status_job02

      - name: Set the statuses of Job 01 and Job 02 as output parameters
        id: set_outputs
        run: |
          echo "::set-output name=status_job01::$(<pass_status_job01/status_job01.txt)"
          echo "::set-output name=status_job02::$(<pass_status_job02/status_job02.txt)"

      - name: Show the values of the outputs
        run: |
          # using the syntax steps.<step_id>.outputs.<output_name> to access the output parameters
          echo "status_job01 = ${{ steps.set_outputs.outputs.status_job01 }}"
          echo "status_job02 = ${{ steps.set_outputs.outputs.status_job02 }}"

      - name: Some other steps of job 03
      . . .
```

In your case, you could eventually use those `status job` outputs to execute or not a job according to their value in an if condition like your suggested in your question (it would probably be in a 4th job after setting them as job3 outputs).

It isn't a *nice* solution (as it's quite verbose), but it works.

Comment: This makes sense but gets very cumbersome for 5+ jobs which I have in a few workflows.

I'm finding adding an `if: failure()` step at the end of each job less cumbersome. Hope github adds support for this soon..